# How to efficiently check if a matrix is a Toeplitz Matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

With `ToeplitzMatrix` we can create a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) from a list of values. I have a question going in the opposite direction, namely, how to efficiently check if a numerical matrix possesses this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatives faster than OP's `ToeplitzMatrixQ`:

```
ClearAll[toeplitzQ1, toeplitzQ2, toeplitzQ3]

toeplitzQ1 = # == ToeplitzMatrix[#[[All, 1]], #[[1]]] &;


toeplitzQ2[m_?SquareMatrixQ] := AllTrue[Diagonal[m, #] & /@ 
   Range[-# + 1, # - 1]&[Length@m], Statistics`Library`ConstantVectorQ]

toeplitzQ3[m_?SquareMatrixQ] := Max[Length[Union[Diagonal[m, #]]] & /@ 
    Range[-# + 1, # - 1] &[Length @ m]] == 1;
```

***Examples:***

```
tm1 = ToeplitzMatrix[{a, b, c, d}, {a, x, y, z}];

RepeatedTiming[#[tm1]] & /@ {toeplitzQ1, toeplitzQ2, toeplitzQ3, ToeplitzMatrixQ}
```

> ```
>  {{4.6*10^-6, True}, {0.00002, True}, {0.000026, True}, {0.00012, True}}
> ```

```
tm2 = ToeplitzMatrix[15];
RepeatedTiming[#[tm2]] & /@ {toeplitzQ1, toeplitzQ2, toeplitzQ3, ToeplitzMatrixQ}
```

> ```
>  {{3.2*10^-6, True}, {0.000043, True}, {0.000072, True}, {0.00037, True}}
> ```

```
tm3 = ToeplitzMatrix[10^3];

RepeatedTiming[#[tm3]] & /@ {toeplitzQ1, toeplitzQ2, toeplitzQ3, ToeplitzMatrixQ}
```

> ```
>  {{0.0045, True}, {0.013, True}, {0.012, True}, {32., True}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

That was a simple question. Anyway, providing an answer, maybe someone will find it useful

```
ToeplitzMatrixQ[A_] := Module[{c, r, a},
  c = A[[All, 1]]; r = A[[1, All]];
  a = ToeplitzMatrix[c, r];
  Norm[a - A] == 0
  ]
```