# Determining whether a matrix is in Jordan canonical form

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, code-review, coding-style

At first, I was surprised that Mathematica doesn't have a built-in function for this, e.g. `JordanMatrixQ`. Anyway, we all know that a Jordan matrix is consisted of block diagonals $J_i$ such that
$$J_i= {\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_i &1&0&\cdots &0\\0&\lambda_i &1&\cdots &0\\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\0&0&0&\lambda_i &1\\0&0&0&0&\lambda_i \end{bmatrix}}$$
So we can easily write a function to check whether a matrix is in Jordan canonical form. First, it has to be upper-triangular and then all the diagonals, except the main and the one above it, must be zero. The last step is taking the [`Differences`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Differences.html) of the main diagonal, like below:

```
jordanMatrixQ[m_]:= UpperTriangularMatrixQ[m] &&
 Union@@(Diagonal[m,#]& /@ Range[2, Length@m-1]) == {0} &&
 And@@MapThread[If[#2==1,#1==0,#2==0]&, {Differences@Diagonal[m], Diagonal[m,1]}]
```

Just for fun (and maybe learning something new along the way), I tried to make a shorter version of this code and shrink its length as far as I could. The result was this:

```
j=With[{m=#,l=Length@#,d=Diagonal},Union@@Join[m~d~#&/@2~Range~l~Join~-Range@l,{If[#2==1,#1,#2]}&~MapThread~{Differences@d@m,m~d~1}]=={0}]&;
```

So 137 bytes was as short as I could get, but I am not satisfied with the result and I think maybe there is a more elegant solution with shorter length that I am missing. Can the above code be optimized *length-wise*? Is there a shorter solution for checking Jordan canonical forms?

<sub>[Related post on meta: Is a question seeking to golf a code on-topic?](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2630)</sub>

Comment: The Jordan block are special Toeplitz matrices. A very similar question about checking whether a matrix is a Toeplitz matrix has been asked here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/235395/9469 . Maybe you can adapt some of the codes.

Comment: `k = IdentityMatrix@Length@# == First@JordanDecomposition@# &` — it’s actually clearer, too, what the purpose is & how it works. Or you can just wait until WRI adds more sugar and maybe the name for this function will be less than “137 bytes”, whatever that means. (E.g., `ByteCount[k] —> 424`, `ByteCount[j] —> 1920`.)

Comment: example? I can’t think of one.

Comment: @MichaelE2 (counter)[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm3xH.png)

Comment: Thanks! $\phantom{}$

Comment: This works on that example: `k = IdentityMatrix@Length@# == ReverseSort@Abs@First@JordanDecomposition@# &;`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Great! Seems to work for every example I could think of. Why not make it into an answer?